# How to replace the Persian dates (١٣٩۶/١٢/٢٩) in Gregorian calendar using vba macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to convert the Persian dates of word file using macro. It is really difficult to convert each date using online converter.

I pasted the date in the code and against each date i pasted the converted date. But i know this is not the a good approach to solve this problem. I am trying to remove the match case to reduce the time and manual inputs.

```
findarray = Array("١٣٩۶/١٢/٢٩ ")
replarray = Array("20/march/2018") * this is sample date
For i = 0 To UBound(findarray)
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
.Text = findarray(i)
.Replacement.Text = replarray(i)
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Next i
```

All dates of the file replace at the same place with out effecting other values and text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying & testing the code taken a hit as the single sample of Arabic date found to have a mix of two different sets of Unicode characters range ( i.e.  1632-1641 and 1776-1785). This is detected only after multiple attempts. However a broad working solution is reached and tested for few recent dates.

Edit: Code modified for Persian date conversion. it used Code used simple conversion method used in [Link1](https://www.computing.net/answers/office/excel-date-problem/16179.html).

```
Option Explicit
Sub testFindLoop()
Dim Rng As Range, Cnt As Long, NumStr As String, SearchPatterns(1 To 2) As String
Dim ArabicTxt As String, HijriTxt As String, GregTxt As String, GregDt As Date
Dim yStr As String, mStr As String, dStr As String
Dim i As Integer, SearchPattern As String

NumStr = "[" & ChrW(1632) & "-" & ChrW(1641) & ChrW(1776) & "-" & ChrW(1785) & "]"
SearchPatterns(1) = "(" & NumStr & "{4})/(" & NumStr & "{1,2})/(" & NumStr & "{1,2})"
SearchPatterns(2) = "([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})"

Cnt = 0
For i = 1 To 2
Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Content
SearchPattern = SearchPatterns(i)
    With Rng.Find
    .Text = SearchPattern
    .MatchWildcards = True

        Do While .Execute
        Cnt = Cnt + 1
        ArabicTxt = Rng.Text
        'Debug.Print Cnt & "-" & ArabicTxt
            If i = 1 Then
            yStr = Left(ArabicTxt, 4)
            mStr = Replace(Mid(ArabicTxt, 6, 2), "/", "")
            dStr = Replace(Right(ArabicTxt, 2), "/", "")
            yStr = ArabicToEnglish(yStr)
            mStr = ArabicToEnglish(mStr)
            dStr = ArabicToEnglish(dStr)
            Else
            yStr = Right(ArabicTxt, 4)
            dStr = Replace(Left(ArabicTxt, 2), "/", "")
            mStr = Replace(Mid(ArabicTxt, IIf(Len(dStr) = 2, 4, 3), 2), "/", "")
            End If
        dStr = IIf(Len(dStr) = 1, "0" & dStr, dStr)
        mStr = IIf(Len(mStr) = 1, "0" & mStr, mStr)
        HijriTxt = yStr & "-" & mStr & "-" & dStr
        'Debug.Print Cnt & "-" & ArabicTxt & "---->" & HijriTxt
        GregDt = Greg_Date(HijriTxt)
        'Debug.Print Cnt & "-" & ArabicTxt & " --> " & HijriTxt & " --> " & Format(GregDt, "dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:ss")
        Rng.Text = Format(GregDt, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
        Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
Next i

'ActiveDocument.SaveAs "C:\users\user\desktop\ArabicTest.Docx"
End Sub
Private Function ArabicToEnglish(sdate As String) As String
Dim i As Integer, AscwVal As Integer
ArabicToEnglish = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(sdate)
    AscwVal = AscW(Mid(sdate, i, 1))
        If AscwVal >= 1632 And AscwVal <= 1641 Then
        ArabicToEnglish = ArabicToEnglish & Chr(AscwVal - 1632 + 48)
        Else
        ArabicToEnglish = ArabicToEnglish & Chr(AscwVal - 1776 + 48)
        End If
    Next
End Function
Function Greg_Date(perDate) As Double
    Const PERSIAN_EPOCH As Long = 1948321 ' The JDN of 1 Farvardin 1
    Dim epbase As Long
    Dim epyear As Long
    Dim mdays As Long
        Dim iYear   As Integer
    Dim iMonth  As Integer
    Dim iDay    As Integer

     iYear = Left(perDate, 4)
     iMonth = Mid(perDate, 6, 2)
     iDay = Right(perDate, 2)
       If iYear >= 0 Then
         epbase = iYear - 474
       Else
         epbase = iYear - 473
       End If
     epyear = 474 + (epbase Mod 2820)
       If iMonth <= 7 Then
         mdays = (CLng(iMonth) - 1) * 31
       Else
         mdays = (CLng(iMonth) - 1) * 30 + 6
       End If
    Greg_Date = CLng(iDay) _
            + mdays _
            + Fix(((epyear * 682) - 110) / 2816) _
            + (epyear - 1) * 365 _
            + Fix(epbase / 2820) * 1029983 _
            + (PERSIAN_EPOCH - 1)
    Greg_Date = Greg_Date - 2415018.5
End Function
```

The `yStr,mStr,dStr` may be required to rearrange depending on date format used in the document.

Comment: This is working but gives me the wrong dates against Persian dates. could you check it at your end. I am giving you the website link to check the correct dates against the persian. [link](https://calcuworld.com/calendar-calculators/persian-calendar-converter/).

Comment: One more thing i also want to do the same for the english numbers as well. Like **1/1/1396** to **english dates.**

Comment: Answer edited for Persian date conversion. Tested for the date sample provided.  .

Comment: I think you miss to add the variable declaration. or may be some global variable declaration.

Comment: Its converting the dates but its giving me with the difference of one day. **1396/12/29 -> 21-Mar-2018** Confirm date : 20-Mar-2018. Could you check it again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Though i don't  know much about Persian dates, Changing `Greg_Date` to double may solve the problem. I think it is something with  12:00 hrs daylight saving time. Editing post in this regard. also added conversion from English numbers  (only for dd/mm/yyyy format.i.e.1/1/1396) to English dates. May please modify to requirement. If only  Persian date conversion is required then modify line `For i = 1 To 2` to `For i = 1 To 1` or make similar modification.